# Why can't my cupy be installed correctly?

Tags: python, cupy

```
nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130

(wbnlu) tf-docker /data0/congmin > nvidia-smi
Fri Dec  4 15:40:43 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.87.01    Driver Version: 418.87.01    CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla M40           On   | 00000000:00:08.0 Off |                  Off |
| N/A   60C    P0   113W / 250W |  11724MiB / 12215MiB |    100%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

(wbnlu) tf-docker /data0/congmin > pip install cupy-cuda100
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.douban.com/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: cupy-cuda100 in /root/.venv/wbnlu/lib/python3.6/site-packages (8.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in /root/.venv/wbnlu/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cupy-cuda100) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: fastrlock>=0.3 in /root/.venv/wbnlu/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cupy-cuda100) (0.5)
```

So my cuda is 10.0 and I installed cupy-cuda100. However, this error shows up:

```
In [1]: import cupy
   ...: a = cupy.zeros((5, 5))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.venv/wbnlu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cupy/__init__.py in <module>
     19             message='can\'t resolve package from __spec__')
---> 20         from cupy import core  # NOQA
     21 except ImportError as e:

~/.venv/wbnlu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cupy/core/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from cupy.core import core  # NOQA
      2 from cupy.core import internal  # NOQA
      3 

ImportError: libnvrtc.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-13f62b8eee5e> in <module>
----> 1 import cupy
      2 a = cupy.zeros((5, 5))

~/.venv/wbnlu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cupy/__init__.py in <module>
     39 original error: {}'''.format(_exc_info[1]))  # NOQA
     40 
---> 41     raise ImportError(_msg) from e
     42 
     43 

ImportError: CuPy is not correctly installed.

If you are using wheel distribution (cupy-cudaXX), make sure that the version of CuPy you installed matches with the version of CUDA on your host.
Also, confirm that only one CuPy package is installed:
  $ pip freeze

If you are building CuPy from source, please check your environment, uninstall CuPy and reinstall it with:
  $ pip install cupy --no-cache-dir -vvvv

Check the Installation Guide for details:
  https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/install.html

original error: libnvrtc.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Why is it complaining about libnvrtc.so.10.0?

Comment: well i face similar issue, even https://pypi.org/project/cupy-cuda100/ is not working!